# Rotate gmaps web api v3 with 2 fingers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I rotate gmaps web api v3 with 2 fingers? I just can't find any info in google documentation  of how to rotate map `<div>` with 2 fingers when it is loaded into a mobile or tactile device.

Answer (score 2):

This is not available in the Maps API JS v3 apart from when you are [45 degree Imagery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery) mode.  There is a FR [to allow changing maps orientation programmatically](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2515),  but it is not yet about 2 finger gesture handling.
Please star it if you want to get updates.

[This article on scrolling and panning behavior](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction) should show you what is possible now

Answer (score 0):

Cooperative gesture handling is the answer you are looking for -

**gestureHandling: 'cooperative'**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction

It allows the users of mobile to swipe the map with one finger to scroll the page and two fingers to pan the map.